# AsymUp function (Rounding) not producing desired results - VB6

Tags: vb6, rounding

I am trying to round up numbers in a legacy application which I had coded in VB6 to obtain the following outcomes:

2.53 should be 2.60

2.55 should be 2.60

2.56 should be 2.60

2.50 should remain 2.50

2.501 should be 2.50

2.505 should be 2.60

I have tried to use the suggested User-Defined Rounding functions by Microsoft
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196652/en-gb

The closest I arrived to is the Asymup function

```
Function AsymUp(ByVal X As Double, _  
Optional ByVal Factor As Double = 1) As Double
Dim Temp As Double
Temp = Int(X * Factor)
AsymUp = (Temp + IIf(X = Temp, 0, 1)) / Factor
End Function
```

I am testing this procedure by calling the function as follows:

```
Text1.Text = AsymUp(Val(Text1.Text), 10)
```

But this is not producing the desired results because 2.60 for example becomes 2.7 when I want it to remain 2.6.  Strangely enough 2.0 also becomes 2.1, implying that the function is not working well.

How can I correct this to acheive the desired results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue using the following code:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
   roundnumber = Val(Text1.Text)
  Text1.Text = Round(roundnumber, 2)
  Text1.Text = AsymUp(Val(Text1.Text), 10)
End Sub

Function AsymUp(ByVal X As Double, _
  Optional ByVal Factor As Double = 1) As Double
  Dim Temp As Double
  Temp = Int(X * Factor)
  AsymUp = (Temp + IIf((X * Factor) = Temp, 0, 1)) / Factor
End Function
```

This is what I was after not precision to 10dp as suggested in this post.

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Function AsymUp(ByVal D As Double, Optional Precision As Double = 1) As Double

    Precision = CDbl("1" & String$(Precision, 48))
    D = D * Precision
    If Int(D) <> D Then
        AsymUp = (Int(D) + 1) / Precision
    Else
        AsymUp = D / Precision
    End If

End Function
```

Visual Basic will always automatically truncate trailing zeros from Double and Single data types. Therefore, unless a function is designed to pass the number back as a string, along with the extra zero(s) appended, it will be impossible to retain trailing zeros of a particular precision.

**Bonus tip:** The IIf function should not be used where performance is of concern, as both the *falsepart* and *truthpart* parameters are always evaluated, regardless of the arguments passed to them.

Comment: Could you please provide me with the decimal number and precision that causes this error? I have tested this code fairly thoroughly, including the sample values you have provided.

Comment: All the numbers seem to cause the error - my code is as follows:

`    Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Text1.Text = AsymUp(Text1.Text, 10)
    End Sub



     Function AsymUp(ByVal D As Double, Optional Precision As Long = 1) As Double
     Precision = CInt("1" & String$(Precision, 48))
     D = D * Precision
     If Int(D) <> D Then
     AsymUp = (Int(D) + 1) / Precision
     Else
     AsymUp = D / Precision
     End If
     End Function`

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected the code. It would appear I did not check it with higher precision values. I will add another answer for keeping zeros tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks tristan look forward to this. I've checked the new code, and no rounding at all is happening!

Comment: If you are still testing with the precision of 10, you will have to make sure use numbers large enough for it to do something (numbers with more than 10 digits after the point). See my previous comment about trailing zeros.

Answer (score 0):

String manipulation method (retains zeros):

```
Private Function AsymUp(ByVal D As Double, Optional Precision As Double = 1) As String

    Dim P As Double, Z As Long
    P = CDbl("1" & String$(Precision, 48))
    D = D * P
    If Int(D) <> D Then
        D = (Int(D) + 1) / P
    Else
        D = D / P
    End If
    AsymUp = CStr(D)
    Z = Precision - (Len(AsymUp) - InStr(AsymUp, "."))
    If Z > 0 Then AsymUp = AsymUp & String$(Z, 48)

End Function
```

This will obviously not be as efficient to run as my other answer, but it's the only way to keep any trailing zeros intact.

Please note that the function will always return the number as a string. You may need to convert the string back to a decimal number to continue using the number with additional mathematics in your program.